# How can I remove the .html extension for static webpages that are indexed so they'll still work in a WordPress site?

Tags: html, htaccess, wordpress, search-engine-indexing, url-rewriting

I have a static HTML website with less than 100 pages and 99 of them are indexed in Google's search engine. I want to convert it into a WordPress website, but there are some problems I'm worried about.

My HTML website pages have an `.html` extension at the end of them and they're indexed with that extension, so converting those pages (even with the same content) to a WordPress page without any extension causes my whole website to be removed from Google's search.

I'm going to need to make sure that the `.html` extension is removed from URLs that already have just an `.html` extension. I want to do this using a  *.htaccess* file. I found the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
^(([^/]+/)*[^/.]+)\.html?$
```

Comment: See this related question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67358/failure-in-redirection-on-the-same-domain-and-folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I helped you with the [**htaccess** file yesterday](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67358/code-for-redirecting-an-html-page-without-an-extension-using-an-htaccess-file-r/67359), I need to offer some advice here:

1. Do not use [Jaun's](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/43278/juan-casta%C3%B1eda) rule as a workaround.
2. Leave both sites up, so the HTML based site stays indexed while you
   work on the WordPress Conversion.
3. Sign Up for [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/), and add both sites to your
   sitelist.
4. Finish the WordPress Conversion, and remove the HTML site using the
   account you created in step 3.
5. Create a Sitemap of the new WordPress site, and submit it to Google for Re-Indexing.
6. Leave the [permanent redirect from yesterday and the Permalink Rewrite Rules](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67358/code-for-redirecting-an-html-page-without-an-extension-using-an-htaccess-file-r/67359) to force all your old visitors to your new site without creating Apache overkill.

Comment: yes i did that but i don't want the wordpress install get indexed so added that directory to robots.txt and i'm gonna redirect those URLs to the new ones from wordpress. but that redirect rule you provided doesn't work anymore but when i try to redirect using cpanel redirect, it is successfully redirected but the cpanel does this using rewrite rules. i don't know if it's good or not.

Comment: i gotta say that my domain is already using wild card redirect to redirect non-www version to www as it's the preferred domain in google webmaster

Comment: However you get the task completed is the important part.  I believe the rule I gave you won't work if you forgot to include the Pretty Permalinks section.

Comment: the Permalinks are set to post name. is that what you mean? 
and i needed to redirect every webpage to its wordpress version not to redirect all pages to index.php. wouldn't have google lost the track of my pages if i'd redirected all pages to index.php?

Comment: See the [Do It Before Posting Section Here](http://digwp.com/2010/07/optimizing-wordpress-permalinks/)  Without Permalinks, all pages get redirected to `index.php?post_id`

Comment: yes i know but to get done with this i created a more country specific directory (i.e en-us instead of en etc) and the redirection works well now. i couldn't manage to redirect two files in the same directory to each other.

Comment: Great!!!  If you need anything else, let me know...

Comment: Alright, Thank you for sharing your information and helping me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is with your regular expression

This sould work fine:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: so if i add it to the htaccess file which is in root folder it will add .html to all pages, But i have 2 wordpress websites in subfolders that don't want their addresses and pages change by this rule. can i still use it?