# Code for redirecting an HTML page without an extension using an .htaccess file results in a 404 error

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect, url-rewriting, nginx

I'm trying to redirect an HTML page to a WordPress page which has no extension. The result of redirecting `example.com/fa/home.html` to `example.com/fa/` is a `404 page not found`. As you can see they're both in a sub-directory.

I've tried many approaches, whether manually or through cPanel to redirect those URLs. Note that I'm using a Nginx web server.

When I try to redirect another URL like `example.com/en/home.html` which is NOT in the `/fa` directory, it will successfully redirect. I have an *.htaccess* file in the root folder and one in the `/fa` directory. I deleted everything in the *.htaccess* file in the `/fa` directory and only left the default index page rule, but still no luck.

The `.htaccess` code in the root directory is:

```
RewriteEngine on
DirectoryIndex Portal.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mscaspian.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mscaspian.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mscaspian.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mscaspian.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.mscaspian.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.mscaspian.com$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ http://www.mscaspian.com [R,NC]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

And the code in the `/fa` directory is:

```
 DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php

 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /fa/
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /fa/index.php [L]
```

Comment: You have to show your redirect code for us to help you

Comment: i added them in the question. they're like the default settings. by the way, my wordpress install folder is in a sub-directory of /fa.

Comment: You need a 301 Redirect, not a URL Rewrite.

Comment: when i do the 301 Redirect in Cpanel it writes 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mscaspian\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mscaspian\.com$
RewriteRule ^fa\/home\.html$ "http\:\/\/www\.mscaspian\.com\/fa\/" [R=301,L]
in the root htaccess

Comment: You state you are using Nginx, but you are using Apache .htaccess directives - how does that work?

Comment: well i don't know..i'm sure it's Nginx, it's like some web hosts use litespeed and some use nginx. isn't that normal?

Comment: It's possible that you have both Nginx and Apache. Nginx might be acting as a front/proxy server? AFAIK, per-directory .htaccess files and `RewriteRule` directives etc. are Apache only, not Nginx.

Comment: yes that might be possible. how to make sure about that and why is something like that needed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will start you off right:   I don't believe the rewrite rule is necessary,  when the default page for WordPress is index.php

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

Redirect 301 ^/home.html http://www.mscaspian.com/fa
```

---

**Update**

[Localizing WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_in_Your_Language)
[List of Localization Plug-Ins](http://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/how-to-localize-your-wordpress-website-using-plugins)

I am not affiliated in any way to the list of plug-ins above, just Googled for:

> localize wordpress content

---

**Update 2**
[List of Common Redirects](http://www.internetmarketingninjas.com/blog/search-engine-optimization/301-redirects/)

As per your comment, you need to add a redirect rule for all pages, as a separate line, Ex:

```
Redirect 301 ^/about.html http://www.mscaspian.com/fa/about
Redirect 301 ^/contact.html http://www.mscaspian.com/fa/contact
```

As I stated earlier, since the default page is index.php. and all these pages are handled by index.php, redirecting to the "Pretty URL" is perfectly legal, only if you have the rules for [Pretty Permalinks Enabled](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Creating_and_editing_.28.htaccess.29), before the redirects.

Comment: i added the the code once in root htaccess and once in /fa directory's, still getting 404 error. the directory is blocked by robots.txt so you can check the live URL.

Comment: Because to Apache your localized version counts as a Directory, and you only need it in the root, as people typing home.html need to go to /fa.  Visitors in /fa are already in the correct place.  See Edit.

Comment: Oh yes now it's redirecting. your edited code works just fine. i have no idea what an ^ can do in there but apparently that just changed everything. Thank you!

Comment: the Carat(^) is a WildCard Character.  Translation: Catch all URL's  that end in /home.html regardless of whats in front of home.html.  Your rule was incorrectly coded because you weren't catching the localized translation language in the path.  Be aware with that rule, that until you localize WordPress, all visitors, regardless of language will be redirected to the Arabic language page

Comment: i have 2 questions. 1st. what if i wanted to use the above rule in the root htaccess instead of the one in the /fa directory. 
and 2nd. i almost localized wordpress for that language but wordpress is so smart that it will know which directory it is in and if the directory's name is one of language code (like fr/fa/en) it will have different response ? 
sorry if i ask simple questions.

Comment: 1. If you want all visitors who are visiting from /home.html to be redirected to /fa, I believe this rule should only go in the root directory. 2. Localizing WordPress only localizes the admin backend. To Localize the content, I would use a plugin.

Comment: thanks, got it. one final question, i did that for fa/home.html to redirect to /fa. i have a couple more urls to redirect but using above rule and replacing address not working for other urls. (e.g. redirecting about.html to /fa/about)

Comment: See the Updated Answer

Comment: thanks, appreciate that. would you please answer my last question i commented. using (Redirect 301 ^/home.html http://www.mscaspian.com/fa) works fine but (Redirect 301 ^/about.html http://www.mscaspian.com/fa/about) fails

Comment: Answered I type slow... Sorry, See update 2.

Comment: i'd vote up your answers if i had enough rep but that's ok i just thank you here.

Comment: All you need is 10 or 25 etc, Once you get it, you can always come back... and you're welcome.

Comment: Yeah of course.

Comment: "the Carat(^) is a WildCard Character" / "using `Redirect 301 ^/home.html mscaspian.com/fa` works fine" - Something a bit strange going on here? This should not work? `Redirect` is a mod_alias directive (so no need for `RewriteEngine on` here) and it does not take a regex as an argument, so the caret(`^`) is not a wildcard character here, it is a literal `^` - so this is not going to match. Also, mixing mod_alias and mod_rewrite directives is not recommended as the outcome is server dependent.